# How to add four white spaces in the lines which locate between `{` and `}`?

Tags: vim, format

The target text file.

```
<style type="text/css">
  #wrap{ 
  height: 550px; 
  width: 660px; 
  }
  #wrap ul{ 
  list-style: none; 
  }
  #wrap li{ 
  border-radius:3px; 
  cursor:pointer; 
  }
  #wrap{ 
  height: 550px; 
  width: 660px; 
  }
  #wrap ul{ 
  list-style: none; 
  }
  #wrap li{ 
  border-radius:3px; 
  cursor:pointer; 
  }
</style>
```

Now i want to add four white spaces at the begining of the lines which locate between `{` and `}` ,to make the above displayed as the below.

```
<style type="text/css">
  #wrap{ 
       height: 550px; 
       width: 660px; 
  }
  #wrap ul{ 
      list-style: none; 
  }
  #wrap li{ 
      border-radius:3px; 
      cursor:pointer; 
  }
  #wrap{ 
      height: 550px; 
      width: 660px; 
  }
  #wrap ul{ 
      list-style: none; 
  }
  #wrap li{ 
      border-radius:3px; 
      cursor:pointer; 
  }
</style>
```

Maybe it is stupid to execute all the commonds to do th task.

```
3,4s/^/    /g
7s/^/    /g
10,11s/^/    /g
14,15s/^/    /g
18s/^/    /g
21,22s/^/    /g
```

Is there more simple and smarty way to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the filetype of your document was correctly set to `html` and your tabulation settings are correct, the following should suffice:

```
:2,23norm ==
```

But, to answer your question directly, you should target the lines containing `:`:

```
:2,23g/:/s/^/    /
```

If you don't want to define the range manually, you could do:

```
vit:g/:/s/^/    /
```

which inserts the `'<,'>` range automatically.

Answer (score -1):

```
:g/^[^<#}]/ normal >>
```

Explanation:

```
: ........... command
g ........... global command (executes on the following pattern
/ ........... start search pattern
^ ........... beginning of line
[^ ] ........ denied list 
<#} ......... denied chars
/ ........... search pattern's end
normal ...... execute in normal mode
>> .......... indentation
```

If this pattern is too recurrent you can put a map on your `~/.vimrc` file, something like this:

```
map <F2> <esc>:g/^[^<#}]/ normal >><cr>
```

the `<cr>` means Carriage Return